# I have an error in Postgresql building a trigger and cannot seem to find a solution

Tags: postgresql-14

I am working in PGAdmin4, learning postgresql (yes, I am still green to this), and trying to build a trigger for a project.

Everything seems to be working well until I get to the create trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Mail_List_upd 
BEFORE UPDATE
ON Mail_List
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE Mail_List_upd_func();
```

When I execute this, in addition to the rest of my code, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"
LINE 73: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Mail_List_upd
         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1824
```

I have gone through all the work and everything looks good.  I as curious if this might be a dialect issue, but that does not seem to be it.  I looked up another person's work on github and tried it and saw the same error.  So I am at a loss.

Comment: Are you sure you are using Postgres **14**? What does `select version();` show you?

Comment: "PostgreSQL 14.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit"

Comment: Do you have any other statements in the SQL editor? Then maybe you forgot to end the previous one with `;`  The statement as shown [is valid](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=bd9d391c0ff707a6f501c058d93691aa)

Comment: Thanks... makes me feel a little better about the work, now I will go back through the rest of my code and make sure that I did not forget something.  are there any "quick and dirty" rules to follow to know what does and does not need the terminator ";" at the end of it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Thanks... and sorry for the delay.  Hell being a student, working full-time, and with a kid in Young Marines.  :-)   I was able to find a section that was missing the ";" and that did correct it.  In fact, there were two missing.  How do I mark you answer as the one that helped so you get the win?  :-)